# Cannot geocode international airport in Berlin, Germany

Tags: geocode, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to geocode an international airport in Berlin, Germany, but the Geocoding API returns ZERO_RESULTS.

The airport in question is Berlin Schönefeld Airport with IATA code SXF. It is the smallest of the two Berlin airports. It is impossible to geocode this airport using any address query I have checked, some of which are:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=SXF&sensor=false
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sch%C3%B6nefeld&sensor=false
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Berlin%20Airport,%20Germany&sensor=false

The funny part is that it was possible to geocode it two or three months ago.
You can also geocode another airport that is now not in use: Tempelhof (THF), because it was replaced by Schönefeld few years ago.

How can I report issues like that?

Google Maps is able to find it without any problems.

EDITED:

For some strange reason Tegel airport is nwo not working by its IATA code either, which is TXL.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=TXL&sensor=false

When I try to search for it using "Tegel Airport" query one of the results is "Sixt Airport Berlin Tegel, 13405 Berlin, Germany" with the following types: "airport", "transit_station" and"establishment", whereas Sixt is a car rental company.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Tegel%20Airport&sensor=false

What's going on?

Comment: Since Schoenefeld Airport was renamed to Berlin Brandenburg International Airport, have you checked if this is potentially merely a naming issue?

Comment: I don't know the status of the airport in question, but according to Wikipedia, Brandenburg Airport is scheduled to open on 27 October 2013. Tempelhof was closed in 2008, Tegel is going to be closed in 2013 and they are somehow appearing in geocoding results, while Schönefeld is not.

Also, Brandenburg is not searchable using its IATA code (BER) and it is not returned when searching for Berlin Airport.

Comment: I think that if it really was the case with just renaming the airport, you should still be able to find it using the old name – people tend to use old names of places for a long time after they were changed, because they are already used to them.